# How to use dummy google account with Android Emulator and Appengine Dev

Tags: google-app-engine, android-emulator

I am working on an web+mobile app that uses App Engine (Java), and uses the Android Accounts API for automatic authentication, using code such as:

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(activity);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

I want to be able to develop offline - using the android emulator and the appengine dev server. How can I set up an account such as `xyz@example.com` (or `xyz@google.com`) on my emulator to be able to use it with `localhost:8888/` urls?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When inside the emulator the hosts localhost interface (the one your dev server is listening to) can be reached with the ip address 10.0.2.2. I think the dev server accepts any google account.